# Spock asserting function calls

Tags: groovy, spock

In Spock I am trying to assert that a method was called with given arguments.

If I do the following the test passes:

```
        1 * snsClient.publish('arn:aws:sns:foo:bar:status', '{"status":"NEW"}')
```

If I do the following the test does not pass:

```
        1 * snsClient.publish('arn:aws:sns:foo:bar:status', JsonOutput.toJson([
                ["status":"NEW"]
        ]))
```

Is there a way to get the second check to pass?

I am using Spock 1.1 with Groovy 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your example, the second one creates a JSON from a list with a single element that is a map.

```
1 * snsClient.publish('arn:aws:sns:foo:bar:status', JsonOutput.toJson([
        ["status":"NEW"]
]))
```

If you want to produce the same result as the first one, don't wrap expected map with a list.

```
1 * snsClient.publish('arn:aws:sns:foo:bar:status', JsonOutput.toJson(["status":"NEW"]))
```